# Using variable in ActiveRecord where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a condition to **filter/search** the **title and user** of the **post** based on the some search keywords.

As you can see the values can be used in where conditions as below two types:

```
Post.where('title ILIKE :keyword or user_name ILIKE :keyword', keyword: "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%")

Post.where('title ILIKE ? or user_name ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%", "#{%params[:search_keyword]}%")
```

First one is by using `variable` directly inside conditions and second one is using the `?` symbol. And first one is easy for me if, there are many variables to compare as I can declare a variable once and use it many times.

Can anyone tell me is there is any **disadvantage** or **security issues** in using the first one or both are same?

Thanks :-)

Comment: According to me second one is best practise rather than the first one.And rather rather calling Post.where its better if you write your filter in helper method and call that helper in Post or where ever required.

Comment: @Erica Bista Is there any reason to second one is best?

Comment: because its more clear and follows standard of search.it also  allows you to search every filed with interpolated value what you wanted to do with your code.
In the first one you are searching for keyword and again interpolating some for that keyword.whereas in second you are searching title with with value.

Comment: I prefer the first way because you don't have to type your variable more than once. It's more DRY IMHO. Image if you were searching name, title, company, email, and bio. Now you have: `"%#{params[:search_keyword]}%", "#{%params[:search_keyword]}%", "%#{params[:search_keyword]}%", "#{%params[:search_keyword]}%","%#{params[:search_keyword]}%"`

Comment: @Dan Yeah. I too prefer 1st one as it is easy and clean to use. Whether both are same are any security issues in first one?

Comment: I think both are equally secure. What you don't want to do is interpolate write in your query string. `where('title ILIKE "%#{params[:search_keywords]}%"')` I believe is more susceptible to shenanigans.

Comment: @Dan OK. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Both ways seems to be fine for me.

For more details, have a look at this rails official guide on security. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: Yeah, I already looked into it but there they are not specified the first type I have used so, I am asking it as a doubt.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Thanks for reply.